# Selecting an item in ComboBox in WPF to do an action

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to initiate an action based on a selection in a ComboBox I created in WPF.  I'm pretty new to WPF and C#.  My ComboBox has

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SampleComboBox" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NameList}" />
```

Where NameList is a List property in the code behind.  Now I want to generate an action based on the selection in the ComboBox and not sure where to start.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a method to handle the `SelectionChanged` event. You can either do this in code:

```
this.MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnSelectionChanged);
```

or in XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SampleComboBox" Width="100" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NameList}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />
```

where you can then do something with the selected items:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
     ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem) (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected object by writing `SampleComboBox.SelectedItem`.
This will return an instance of an item in your source list.

Answer (score 0):

Are these a finite set of values in this NameList that is the ItemsSource for this?

Why not amend that xaml to read:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SampleComboBox" Width="100" SelectedItem="{Binding TheItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NameList}" />
```

and then in your ViewModel for this, have something like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TheItemProperty=
    DependencyProperty.Register("TheItem", typeof(string), typeof(OrderEditorViewModel), 
        new PropertyMetadata((s, e) => {
            switch (e.NewValue) {
                case "SomeValue":
                    // Do something
                    break;
                case "SomeOtherValue":
                    // Do another thing
                    break;
                default:
                    // Some default action
                    break;
             }
     }));

public string TheItem{

  get { return (string)GetValue(TheItemProperty); }
  set { SetValue(TheItemProperty, value); }
}
```

You can do your actions based on the selection in that switch statement which will be invoked whenever the selection is changed.